# Python module can't be imported when triggered by launchctl script in macos

Tags: python, macos, info.plist, launchctl, root.plist

[The python program(apple.py) which wanted to be triggered by launchctl script,written under python2.7 in anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEyiB.png)

[The launchctl plist script(com.tushare.refreshall.plist) which was used to trigger the python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mjCU.png)

I try to use a plist script to launch my python program but in vain,in the program,i import a package tushare,but "ImportError: No module named tushare" returned in log file "stderr",this package can be successfully imported in python program written in anaconda.

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/jacksonshawn/PythonCodes/apple.py", line 8, in <module>
import tushare as ts

ImportError: No module named tushare
```

Guess maybe it's due to "EnvironmentVariables" parameter missing in plist script,but i don't know how to amend the plist script to fix the problem.Every time,i do the following to execute the script.Syntax checked with the Plist script,it can be executed.

```
"launchctl unload -w com.tushare.refreshall.plist"

"launchctl load -w com.tushare.refreshall.plist"

"launchctl start com.tushare.refreshall.plist"
```

Comment: Anyone can help?really appreciate it.This module tushare works well in python 2.7 within anaconda,i just didn't know why it can't be imported in program which needed to be triggered by launchctl script.Maybe some parameter like "EnvironmentVariables" missing in my plist script.

Comment: Add some debug to your code that prints the value of sys.path. Make sure that the module you are importing is on the sys.path.

Comment: Try to create a virtual environment on python2 and do the project. And try installing tushare in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

The service you are starting with launchctl likely does not share the environment you are in when you login into the terminal including the anaconda configuration.

You can fix this by adjusting the plist's `ProgramArguments` key and run whatever you intent through bash first and include the conda activation before the intended program. Here is an example where the emacs daemon is run in a conda environment named `py36`:

```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>source /Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh; conda activate py36; /usr/local/opt/emacs/bin/emacs --fg-daemon</string>
  </array>
```

This assumes that you are `username`, with anaconda installed in `/Users/username/anaconda3`. Adjust as per your specifics including the conda environment name.

Comment: thank you very much, i will give a shot as what you told.